# ARM template error 'properties.api' is not valid from parameter file?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have created `parameter file` for `LogicApp project`.

When I try to deploy using this parameter file it is giving following `error` -

```
 Template deployment returned the following errors:
Resource MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS 'demo-sbs' failed with message '{
   "error": {
     "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
     "message": "The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'The 'id' property 'aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/servicebus' under 'properties.api' is not valid.'."
   }
 }'
```

LogicApp.dev.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "value": "demoapp"
    },
    "ResourceGroupName": {
      "value": "demo1"
    },
    "logicAppLocation": {
      "value": "westeurope"
    },
    "logicAppEnvironment": {
      "value": "DEV"
    },
    "sbs_Name": {
      "value": "demo-sbs"
    },
    "sbs_Connection_Name": {
      "value": "demo-sbs"
    },
    "sbs_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "value": "demo-sbs"
    },
    "nok_cb2b_we_sbs_connectionString": {
      "value": "Endpoint=sb://demo-sbs.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=asdasd/assasad"
    },
    "LogicAppIntegrationAccountName": {
      "value": "intdemo"
    },
      "subscriptionId": {
          "value": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaaaa"
      }
  }
}
```

LogicApp.json (resources section)

```
"resources": [

    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('demo-sbs_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(parameters('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('logicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'servicebus')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('demo-sbs_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "connectionString": "[parameters('demo-sbs_connectionString')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

the problem is with below line - 
when I tried to use parameter for subscriptionId like `concat(parameters('subscriptionId')` it give above error and if I use `concat(subscription().id` it works fine.
I want to use parameter for `subscriptionId` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for what you are doing:

```
                "api":{  
                "id":"[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/serviceBus')]"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, thats because thats not how resource id looks like in azure.

```
/subscriptions/subscription_guid/resourceGroups/resource_group_name/providers/microsoft.insights/components/resource_name
```

this is how it looks. to créate it you could use `resourceId` function. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid)

Or you can use concat, but you would need to créate the same string, you can use `resourceGroup().id` to help you with that.

Comment: the problem is with below line - when I tried to use parameter for subscriptionId like concat(parameters('subscriptionId') it give above error and if I use concat(subscription().id it works fine. I want to use parameter for subscriptionId also.

Comment: like i said, `subscription().id` returns not just the guid, it returns `/subscriptions/subscription_guid`, also I have no idea how resourceId can work without resource group in it (there are resources like this, but really seldom)

Comment: let me try like this  "id": "`[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('subscriptionId')`